# Interactive matplotlib under windows

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib

When I am in an interactive python session (usually IPython), the following commands:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
```

do not automatically raise a window, showing the plot. The only way I can make matplotlib actually raise the window is using `show()`, which also captures all input until I close the window destroying the plot. Now I have to give all my plot commands before I can see any result, which is a major nuisance. On OSX, I do not have this issue.

The backend I'm using is TkAgg. Using `draw()` and `ion()` calls has no effect.

Comment: what do you want to do with your plot once you have displayed it? The behavior you describe on osx is strange: what if you only want to save the plot in a jpeg? Does it also open a windows when you call plot?

Comment: With MacOSX as backend it always shows the plot, even with `interactive(False)`. When I use TkAgg as backend on OSX it behaves normally. Maybe a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use IPython pylab mode, this works:

```
In [1]: plot([1,2,3,4])
Out[1]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x020F75B0>]
```

there is not need for show() nor matplotlib import.

In IPython normal mode you can make your session interactive. This also works:

```
In [4]: from matplotlib import interactive

In [5]: interactive(True)

In [6]: from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

In [7]: plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
Out[7]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x00F89D50>]
```